# .htaccess 301 redirect doamin A to domain B subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, http-redirect

can someone help me how can I 301 redirect all pages of my old "siteA" to new "siteB/X"?
(X is my sub folder)

question 2:
If you want to redirect for example 50 websites' root to this "siteB/x", is it possible with one .htaccess file? what should I write in htaccess file? (all those 50 websites are in same host and they pointed to a same single folder witch my .htaccess file is located there)

Thanks

I'm new to this and tried several methods but I couldn't find a solution yet. Please help

Comment: Where does `siteB` point to? Are you wanting to redirect to the same URL-path inside the `X` subdirectory? Or literally just to `/X`? "tried several methods but I couldn't find a solution yet" - Please include what you have tried. And why these did not work for you.

Comment: In fact I want to redirect both "www.siteA.com" & "www.siteB.com" to "www.siteB.com/x". (consider X subdirectory as my forum); and in future I want to use "www.siteB.com" for another purpose. But For now if someone type "www.siteA.com" or "www.siteB.com" he must redirected to "www.siteB.com/x" (not only main url but all links of siteA)

Answer (score 0):

Currently I added following code in "siteB" root directory for redirect it to "siteB/x"

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^siteB\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.siteB.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ fa [L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php$ /X/index.php
```

and it working fine.
But my problem is with siteA redirection. I used following code in siteA root dirctory and it redirecting siteA to siteB/x for main domain (but other links not working and they send error).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.siteB.com/$1 [R=301,L]    
    RewriteRule ^$ X [L]
    </IfModule>
```

I mean for example, currently, if I enter [www.siteA.com](http://www.siteA.com) in browser it will redirect it to [www.siteB.com/x](http://www.siteB.com/x) with no problem.
But if I enter [www.siteA.com/articles](http://www.siteA.com/articles) it will redirect to [www.siteB.com/articles](http://www.siteB.com/articles) which is incorrent. ( I need to redirect to [www.siteB.com/X/articles](http://www.siteB.com/X/articles))
I hope you understanding what I mean